# Is it possible to perform validation of data in data extensions in SFMC automatically?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data, automation

Currently, we have a ton of AdHoc (one-time emails) each month and for each email:

- the email creative is different
- audience list and DE fields are different

So, every time we get the list imported into data extension, we need to have a team member manually review the data to validate that all columns are populated correctly, there are no issues with the data.

**Question -** Is there any way to perform validations automatically or with the help of any scripts / SQL to remove manual step / manual validation?

Just looking for advise on creating automated processes.

Comment: What is common between sends?  If the email creative  _and_ send context is different every send, then I don't see how you'd have any opportunity to automate the validation.  Email architectures should reduce production time, but if all of the sends aren't conforming to one, then perhaps they should.

Comment: Agreed with @AdamSpriggs here - I think this is more of a process problem that could cause major issues in scalability and risk (which seems like are starting to show up already). Building a custom validation tool is not likely to be a worthwhile investment as it would likely be a high up front investment and then with the constant changes of the emails/data, you would likely need to constantly change the tool...

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs and Gortonington for sharing your feedback. Is it common for businesses to have a custom script or SQL or ssjs or something to validate data in data extensions? Just trying to understand how data can be validated in an automated fashion (keeping email creative aside)? Is there any way to NOT check data for each month's email manually? Can these steps be automated to validate - certain fields are populated, data is correct etc?

Comment: I would love to hear you in your organization (OR if you work with clients) validate audiences? how do you validate data that is changing each time / each month? Do you update automations with email UIs manually to honor any email changes OR there is another 'better / optimized' way to  do that?

Comment: Common schemas for sending lend themselves to common email architectures.  I'd recommend a "master" sending schema and every incoming data source is conformed to it with a staging->master query.  This type of query would enforce the naming conventions, supplement and qualify sendable data.  Then your email scripting can be common across sends.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs for your feedback - Totally agree with you, consistency = optimized process. Just curious do you have any examples / use-cases how master queries should look like that is capable to enforce naming conventions and sendable data?